# How use get_queryset in Django Admin for retrieve only objects created by AdminUser?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-queryset, django-users

I have an app with 3 kind of users:

- RegularUsers: Users of the app. Can't login admin site. They are managed by AdminUsers. They are the final users of the app.
- AdminUsers: They can login admin site in order to manage their RegularUsers. They just can manage users created by themselves.
- SuperUser. The admin of the WebApp having all permissions.

I have different Models too. The website is a webGallery. Above you have my

### MODELS.PY

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    descripcion = models.TextField(blank=True)
    telefono = PhoneNumberField()
    avatar = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Imagen de perfil',
                               upload_to='img/avatars',
                               default='img/placeholder-image.png')
    def __str(self):
        return self.username

class RegularUser(MyUser):
    MyUser.is_staff = False
    MyUser.is_superuser = False

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Usuario Regular'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Usuarios Regulares'

class AdminUser(MyUser):
    usuarios = models.ManyToManyField(RegularUser,    help_text="Selecciona los usuarios que administra", blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Administrador'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Administradores'

class Album(models.Model):
    id_album = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False)
    ...
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ....
    # admin = models.ForeignKey(Familiar, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="Administrador") ??¿¿
    evento = models.ForeignKey(Evento, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

class Multimedia(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    keyword = models.ManyToManyField('Keyword', help_text="Selecciona las palabras clave para etiquetar.")
    ......


class Imagen(Multimedia):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image_width = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=640)
    image_height = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=480)
    fichero_imagen = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Archivo de imagen',
                                       upload_to='files/img',
                                       width_field='image_width',
                                       height_field='image_height')
    thumbnail = ImageSpecField(source='fichero_imagen',
                               processors=[ResizeToFill(600, 300)],
                               format='JPEG',
                               options={'quality': 60})

    def filename(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.fichero_imagen.name)
```

### ADMIN.PY

```
....
@admin.register(Album)
class AlbumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['titulo', 'descripcion', 'thumbnail', 'evento', 'usuario']
    date_hierarchy = 'fecha_creacion'
    list_filter = ('fecha_creacion', 'usuario')
    inlines = [ImagenInstanceInline]

    # def get_queryset(self, request):
    #     qs = super(AlbumAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    #     if request.user.is_superuser:
    #         return qs
    #     return qs.filter( = request.user)

@admin.register(Imagen)
class ImagenAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('preview', 'titulo',)
    exclude = ('path',)
    #fields = ('image_tag',)
    readonly_fields = ('vista_previa',)

    def vista_previa(self, obj):
        return mark_safe('<img style="border-radius:25px;" src="{url}" width="{width}" heigth={heigth} />'.format(
            url=obj.fichero_imagen.url,
            width=300,
            heigth=300,
        )
        )
    def preview(self, obj):
        return mark_safe('<img style="border-radius:25px;" src="{url}" width="{width}" heigth={heigth} />'.format(
            url=obj.fichero_imagen.url,
            width=100,
            heigth=100,
        )
        )
    # def get_queryset(self, request):
    #     qs = super(ImagenAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    #     if request.user.is_superuser:
    #         return qs
    #     return qs.filter(author = request.user)
```

...

In get_queryset, I don't know how to access Admin User in order to compare it with request.user. My final purpose is that users can only see the content created by their admin user, that is, by the user who created the album.

Comment: Is Album.usuario the user that created the Album object?

Comment: No. The purpose of usuario field is to assign the RegularUser who can view the Album. This field is filled by the Administrator User when creating a new instance of Album in the Django Admin Site. So the administrator can assign an album to one of their users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use Djangos [LogEntry](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#logentry-objects)? This will work only when objects are created via the Admin. If not you'll have to add a user field to Album to store who created it.

For example:

```
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry, ADDITION
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

@admin.register(Album)
class AlbumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    ...

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(AlbumAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs

        album_ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Album)
        log_entries = LogEntry.objects.filter(
            content_type=album_ct, 
            user=request.user,
            action_flag=ADDITION
        )
        user_album_ids = [a.object_id for a in log_entries]
        return qs.filter(id__in=user_album_ids)
```

A similar approach can be taken with ImagenAdmin.

I suppose you could also hijack django.contrib.admin.models.LogEntryManager to log an addition when done by some other means (views.py etc).

Comment: Thanks!!! It works! Now I can extend this to all my models. I'll look up more information about log_entries. I see that django is a very powerful framework but at the same time difficult to handle all the functionality.